# Entity Framework core get latest entities for multiple types

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I am build an endpoint to fetch the latest objects from my DB with ef core.
My code is

```
private AppUser GetLatestUser()
{
  if (context.Roles.Any())
  {
    var max = context.Users.Max(x => x.UpdatedAt);
    return context.Users.Where(x => x.UpdatedAt == max).FirstOrDefault();
  }
  return null;
}
private AppRole GetLatestRole()
{
  if (context.Roles.Any())
  {
    var max = context.Roles.Max(x => x.UpdatedAt);
    return context.Roles.Where(x => x.UpdatedAt == max).FirstOrDefault();
  }
  return null;
}
.....
```

I want to avoid using nearly the same code for every entity I have. Would like to use a type as parameter, but no idea how to do this.

Comment: Why are you doing two queries to retrieve one row? You should consider `.OrderBy(x => UpdatedAt).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @bradbury9, I agree with you, except that in the combined approach, OP will need  OrderByDescending() instead of OrderBy()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something like this

```
private T GetLatestEntry(T entity) where T : class
{
    return context.Set<T>().OrderByDescending(x => UpdatedAt).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` will still return `null` if there are no entries. There's no reason to use `Any()`, that's just another query

Comment: in this approach, OP needs OrderByDescending().

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos true.. i didnt really pay attention to that

Comment: Note that you should add ' where T : class ' and change class to a generic interface that has the property of UpdatedAt, plus should be Set<T>()

Comment: You could be extra cheeky here and turn this into an IQueryable extension so that you could call 

"return context.Users.Where(x => x.UpdatedAt == max).GetLatestEntry()";

Comment: @TiagoSilva you can edit the answer if I put this wrong

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim yep thats correct but the OP  now must create an interface that has that property

Comment: Worked :) Will use it for my entities. But since User and Role are from IIdentity i will use the none generic methods for them.